# Decompress a ragged list

Tags: code-golf, ragged-list

Your input is a ragged list of possibly empty lists of non-negative integers. For example, `[[2,0],[[]],[[[],[1],[]],[]]]` is a valid input. This input is a "compressed" ragged list. What this means is that when we have a list of numbers, we interpret those as a list of indices, indexing the output.

For example, if `I=[[2,0],[[]],[[[],[1],[]],[]]]` then the decompressed list is `O=[[[[],[[]],[]],[[]],[[[],[[]],[]],[]]]`, because if we replace `[2,0]` with `O[2][0]=[[],[[]],[]]` and `[1]` with `O[1]=[[]]` in the input list, we get `O` as the output.

The naïve method is just to have the input as a working list and then iteratively replace lists of numbers with by indexing the working list. However this runs into two potential problems:

First, consider an input like `I=[[1,0,0,0],[2],[[[[]]]]]`. Here if we index this input like so: `I[1][0][0][0]` we will get an index error. We would have to first replace `[2]` with `I[2]` giving `tmp=[[1,0,0,0],[[[[]]]],[[[[]]]]]`. Now we can replace `[1,0,0,0]` with `tmp[1][0][0][0]` giving `O=[[],[[[[]]]],[[[[]]]]]` as the output.

Another difficulty is that we can get a form of co-recursion with inputs like `[1],[[0,1],[]]`. This decompresses to `[[[],[]],[[],[]]]`

Full blown infinite recursion like `[[0]]` or `[[1],[[0],[0]]]` won't happen though.

## Rules

Your input is a ragged list `I` that may contain lists consisting of only numbers. Your task is to find a ragged list `O`, containing only lists, where if you replace every list `L` of numbers in `I` by `O[L]` you get `O` as the output. Your program must output `O`. You may assume that a unique solution exists.

You can choose between 0- and 1-based indexing. You can also choose the order of the indices, i.e. whether `[2,3,4]` corresponds to `O[2][3][4]` or `O[4][3][2]`.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins.

## Examples

```
[] -> []
[[],[[],[]]] -> [[],[[],[]]]
[[[],[]],[[0],[0]],[[1],[1]]] -> [[[],[]],[[[],[]],[[],[]]],[[[[],[]],[[],[]]],[[[],[]],[[],[]]]]]
[[[],[[],[],[[]]]],[0,1,2]] -> [[[],[[],[],[[]]]],[[]]]
[[1,0,0,0],[2],[[[[]]]]] -> [[],[[[[]]]],[[[[]]]]]
[[1],[[],[0,0]]] -> [[[],[]],[[],[]]]
[[1],[[2,0,2],[0,0],[]],[[1],[0]]] -> [[[],[],[]],[[],[],[]],[[[],[],[]],[[],[],[]]]]
```

Comment: Took me a few minutes to make sense of this but it’s a nice challenge

Comment: Would like to see one that work well for infinite recurse. [Tried one](https://tio.run/##bVHBboQgEL37FXscWpZVj22wxyY9tIceCXFR0bCxatRu1J@3gxqibUNghjfvzTDMTd1Vl7am6c9Vnel5zvnAIyj4yKORfakGYKKG8GgSvnz0Obf2ZWRxnOncVPpV971u4xgMjZHEWp19pxpA0QRFSiSSDoQ8FTARQmAg87N39YQ8naOTkJ4Qki5byhXa3TG4eoj4ePiLF@AROLYjOGfVWuQf6Ii4EsvdmoXm04CG@wLH8Pa0gPp2IRBu1eShB0cXrlSw5bKyPw24nhdWiLnDjboRgvUL9rqddP8Nv2DMesWxNKXCuVyAPRCbwtpLQSGm66TSuurqUrOyLkAN/O3z4511fWuqwuQj5KDvqgSFM6QJxThPCPHmHw) but it fail JSON stringifying

Comment: You could make understanding the question a bit easier by formatting `I` to be on several lines, making it visually parseable. I had to copy paste `I` and `O` to an editor to make sense of the brackets (the first `O=` is missing a final bracket, by the way).

Comment: Also, I believe "inputs like `[1],[[0,1],[]]`" is supposed to have a wrapping pair of brackets around it (maybe it's implied, but best to have it explicit).

Comment: "the first `O=` is missing a final bracket" <-- actually, it just has an extra initial one that's to be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>94</s> <s>90</s> <s>87</s> <s>86</s> 85 bytes

```javascript
f=(x,n,s=(g=y=>y[0]>=' '?n=y.map(b=>e=e[b]||0,e=x)<e.map?e:y:y.map(g))(x))=>n?f(s):s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHBboQgEIbvPsXeHLqsCx63Re89tIceKemiRWNj0chmo8k@TJ@lL2ZBDdG2EGD4@WaGgQ95lSbvqvZy0M27GseCQY81NgxKNrBk4EQkLPz@ClPNhuhTtpCxRDHFM3G7EaxYjx6U01N1Gk4zUSIEPUIs0WkBBp3MeB@cAy52h2THRcC5wNMQYpZWe3s4W1YhdiKTRe1EPe0Bb8y@TvlH2io@xbR3y4QRTHG8TrA9Xq5GMXHdCvGSTWxq8Dj3qegSy7n9KcDXPFGxjR0v6ALQ@QnWfivX9TP8km3Uc9Sptpa5giNEd8iFcOuxxPCGJc7s/@SNNk2toropAWTPHl@enyJz6SpdVsUABairrEEi2/bhqw73GbYUyxAKxh8)

After `y[0]>=` is U+00A0

Comment: Brilliant solution! I started to work on mine but it is way over 87 bytes. ;)

Comment: @brotherFilip I think it quite intended and how's yours?

Comment: @tsh Fail if `y` is `[]`

Comment: @tsh `[][0]` is `undefined` and `undefined+0==undefined`&`undefined+0>undefined` are both false

Comment: `y[0]+0==y[0]` -> `x[y[0]+0+0]`

Comment: @tsh Fail if `x[100]` exist and `y[0]==[1]`

Comment: `y[0]+0==y[0]` -> `x[0+y[0]+0]` should be correct then...

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 138 bytes

```
def f(x):
 def g(y):y[:]=h(x,y)if[]<y<[f]else map(g,y)*0+y
 h=lambda z,y:h(x,z+y)if[]<z<[f]else(h(z[y[0]],y[1:])if y[1:]else z[y[0]]);g(x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVBBboMwEFSvvGKVk2mcCHOqaNKPWD5QgYMlBxC4VcwT-oVecqn6pvY1XRvXIW2EsGdnZ3bX-_7ZW9N0bX4-f7wYuXn4eqtqCZKc0iIBBw_EpoXlhdg35ERtqiQXO7vjUtR6rOFY9uSA9H22tgk0e10en6sSJmoLp5_WwTH9OkhDJm55JgS1nBUC0-CBLxdS6eMBJwgTGXXsu8HAaMdEdgNoUK0LtqOpVLsd6rLSqq1H4kYGRTvY-7Hq11JTvR17rQxZweYJVmmKin5QrSHqArsLlMhjCxV6n7_vei6clYuEc0H9L8RMLWJMzgiZDI_MI4YHi-ooiGD2OuYGdc3EFj52l5dllNF82eA6HUZjNHMfEnnoJq7eEOU8tmKhlrP9e0B8s1flWDsP0iBg8wqWvoV1uYY_NFadN_8D)

"Decompresses" the list in-place.

Function `g` does the main recursion. Function `h` looks ahead to resolve individual multi-step compressions where needed. The main purpose of function `f` is to put `x` in the closures of `g` and `h`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 126 bytes

```clj
#(loop[a %](letfn[(g[x](let[y(get-in a x)](cond(=[]x)x(coll? y)y(every? coll? x)(mapv g x)1 x)))](if(= a(g a))a(recur(g a)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLRboQgEHy/r9h4abIk2oqPl9zdhxAeiKKxoWoVL/r1dgFjsK0GnB1mdoWlNP3nPOoNK11DvV3R9P0gFLxJNNrWncBGLB6LFRtts7YDBQuTWPZdhXchF7YQNuYJK1tRv/S4PiEQC8MvNbygIcRpMLK1Nd5BYQOKMYWjLucxBPRs7IJVP@lvEFZPFsQlERKyBwiZEBQy9UPKQEaxXw6YuJym3CNOEz/0h@AAwe2Yf6gzExXxjPt4YZ7ytIhLnJeP3@Np7l6iir2iPO3kMIioHN/zOeOfbUR797qC8he7eJfwcBSxMzLHx/GLdnnl5UaNJx81vZ@tBNdOGLWqssmObdcAluH@vIf4YxpMa8E375pkj4Qxkk@ANbQdk5QQB9JZ01EMTuDyQnJLgG6FU1LoLsIP)

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 353 bytes:

```py
from itertools import*
S=str
g=lambda x:[x]if x and int==type(x[0])else[j for k in x for j in g(k)]
def r(v,p):
 for i in p:
  try:
   l=v
   for x in i:
    l=l[x]
   v=eval(S(v).replace(S(i),S(l)))
  except:return 0
 return [0,v][all(i in'[], 'for i in S(v))]
f=lambda x:i[0]if(i:=[l for i in permutations(g(x),len(g(x)))if(l:=r(eval(S(x)),i))])else i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPBjpswED2Xrxjlgl25EaSXCsn9hF5ydK3K2ZjUuwYs24vI16czhKVk2xUCz7z3xjNjM@Gafw/9128h3m5tHDpw2cY8DD6B68IQ8@fiKFOOxUV6053OBqZGTdq1MIHpz@D6LGW@BssmVWlufbLqGdohwgtyKCLzmcwLe@G6ONsWIhtF4E0xc464gA7keKUFvBxpIXIi0s0owh4TkzlKOxrPjmzk@2iDN08WHcfFkXnOOUrs9GRDbqLNr7GHqoDFUpUYtTLeM0pbKi2gXIug/bDC9m@jDltyLXONVH5TrI3dazbZDX1iFzZx4W0/G5yj2jcysqVAhITDTedzAXdLcrfbFUrDl@@gdKGwgPnV@g5tfCRr8ipRbwV3dqtakQo/1WxRRP1vyLtYQv4DPSJritmnZZZhVeKwTfBIvzUgKnoQOCzZ9EOnq1ytqeplLwr7uOdZdcC9D4t0EdT3I9jGbUK3x/AO1pou5v7Hg0m5WG@7dR4ngv0Yeisg7VPwLrPyZ19y/IM/GQEnkNCZwDBq72l6jP9F1y/AvampHNSjPCWcLmiZ4SAlnIoQcYBYmW3KCQLR55Lf/gA)

Comment: [345](https://tinyurl.com/8rhpxv7t)